# Echo ''0'' from database,doesnt work

Tags: php, sql, echo

I have column in database "blabla", it is varchar 55, utf8_general_ci and it's value is "0", not empty,but as number zero.

When i try my code:

```
echo $row['blabla'];
```

It won't echo anything.

If it's 1 or more,or letters it does echo.

What do i change,so it would actually echo that "0"?

I'm sorry if it's noob question ^^

Thanks!

```
 $champions_q = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM `champions` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$champions_q->execute();
while($row = $champions_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $champ_name = $row['name'];

  <td class="box"> <b> Total deaths:  
                    </b>  <?php if(empty($row['total_deaths']) === false){ echo '<b id="value_box">'.$row['total_deaths']; } ?> </b> 
                    <td width="15"></td></td>
```

Total deaths,are 0 in database.

Thanks everyone,solved :)

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: `echo '0';` outputs 0. You have another issue.

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` to find out what's wrong.

Comment: [works fine here](https://eval.in/99058)

Comment: try echo (string)$row['blabla'];

Comment: I'm confuse with what you mean here **What do i change,so it would actually echo that "0"?**, do you mean you want to output `0 with a ""`?

Comment: Is your "0" value TRULY a zero character and not actually NULL? Be sure to test for this first: `select * where NOT IS NULL`

Comment: var_dump(empty(0)) returns true... therefore your if condition is failing

Comment: When i use echo $row['total_deaths']; outside of form,it does echo "0" and yes my value is "0" not NULL!

Comment: empty(0) returns true... (empty($row['total_deaths']) === false) <- this condition fails

Comment: But it's not empty,there's number 0

Comment: yes agreed... empty() is a function that checks for 'emptiness'... 0 is empty as per this function... therefore it returns true :)

Comment: Don't use say that your question is solved. Either accept one of the fine answers below or detail the solution in your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `if` is contrary to what you want to achieve. If `$row['total_deaths']` is `0` then it will surely fail in `if(empty($row['total_deaths']) === false)` because `empty(0)` is true.

Try changing your `if` to something like this:

```
$champions_q = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM `champions` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$champions_q->execute();
while($row = $champions_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $champ_name = $row['name'];

  <td class="box">
  <b> Total deaths:</b>
  <?php
    if (empty($row['total_deaths']))
      echo '<b id="value_box">0</b>';
    else 
      echo '<b id="value_box">'.$row['total_deaths'].'</b>';
  ?>
  <td width="15"></td>
  </td>
```

If-else shorthand way:

```
$champions_q = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM `champions` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$champions_q->execute();
while($row = $champions_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $champ_name = $row['name'];

  <td class="box">
  <b> Total deaths:</b>
  <?php echo (empty($row['total_deaths']) ? '<b id="value_box">0</b>' : '<b id="value_box">'.$row['total_deaths'].'</b>'); ?>
  <td width="15"></td>
  </td>
```

Comment: It did echo "0" now,but when i add value 1 or more to that column,then it doesnt echo.

Comment: Ah thank you,i figured it out now,what i did was:
if(empty($row['total_deaths']) or !empty($row['total_deaths']))

Comment: Yes that was just it. Pardon if my answer goes with a if/else shorthand style as I was used to doing if-else that way.

Comment: @user3271329, if you're going to do `if(empty($row['total_deaths']) or !empty($row['total_deaths']))` then you may as well remove the if statement all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$champions_q = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM `champions` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$champions_q->execute();
while($row = $champions_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $champ_name = $row['name'];

  <td class="box"> <b> Total deaths:  
                    </b>  <?php if($row['total_deaths'] != ''){ echo '<b id="value_box">'.$row['total_deaths']; } ?> </b> 
                    <td width="15"></td></td>
```

Comment: A little explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Comment: What OP had used: empty(0)... but returns true... (empty($row['total_deaths']) === false) <- this condition fails... empty() is a function that checks for 'emptiness'... 0 is empty as per this function... therefore it returns true. So instead we can compare if it is not a blank value... it will suffice the change OP asked for